# multiple file text replace with sed

Tags: bash, text-processing, find, sed

I try to replace some texts in text files with `sed` but don't know how to do it with multiple files.
I use:

```
sed -i -- 's/SOME_TEXT/SOME_TEXT_TO_REPLACE/g /path/to/file/target_text_file
```

Before i go with the multiple files i printed the paths of targeted text files in a text file with this command:

```
find /path/to/files/ -name "target_text_file" > /home/user/Desktop/target_files_list.txt
```

Now i want to run `sed` according to `target_files_list.txt`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can loop through the file using `while ... do` loop:

```
$ while read i; do printf "Current line: %s\n" "$i"; done < target_files_list.txt
```

In your case you should replace `printf ...` with `sed` command you want.

```
$ while read i; do sed -i -- 's/SOME_TEXT/SOME_TEXT_TO_REPLACE/g' "$i"; done < target_files_list.txt
```

However, notice that you can achieve what you want using only `find`:

```
$ find /path/to/files/ -name "target_text_file" -exec sed -i -- 's/SOME_TEXT/SOME_TEXT_TO_REPLACE/g' {} \;
```

You can read more about `-exec` option by running `man find | less '+/-exec '`:

> ```
>    -exec command ;
>
>           Execute command; true if 0 status is returned.  All
>           following arguments to find are taken to be arguments to
>           the command until an argument consisting of `;' is
>           encountered.  The string `{}' is replaced by the current
>           file name being processed everywhere it occurs in the
>           arguments to the command, not just in arguments where it
>           is alone, as in some versions of find.  Both of these
>           constructions might need to be escaped (with a `\') or
>           quoted to protect them from expansion by the shell.  See
>           the EXAMPLES section for examples of the use of the
>           -exec option.  The specified command is run once for
>           each matched file.  The command is executed in the
>           starting directory.  There are unavoidable security
>           problems surrounding use of the -exec action; you should
>           use the -execdir option instead.
> ```

### EDIT:

As correctly noted by users
[terdon](https://askubuntu.com/users/85695/terdon) and [dessert](https://askubuntu.com/users/507051/dessert) in the comments
it's necessary to use `-r` with `read` because it will correctly
handle backslashes. It's also reported by `shellcheck`:

```
$ cat << EOF >> do.sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh
while read i; do printf "$i\n"; done < target_files_list.txt
EOF
$ ~/.cabal/bin/shellcheck do.sh

In do.sh line 2:
while read i; do printf "\n"; done < target_files_list.txt
      ^-- SC2162: read without -r will mangle backslashes.
```

So it should be:

```
$ while read -r i; do sed -i -- 's/SOME_TEXT/SOME_TEXT_TO_REPLACE/g' "$i"; done < target_files_list.txt
```

Comment: `read` will not see the last line of the input file if it doesn't end with a newline character, I recommend `while IFS='' read -r i || [[ -n "$i" ]]; do …` instead.

Comment: I appreciate your remark. However, note that user uses `>` that will handle new lines automatically and that it's common in `unix` world to end files with newilne: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-text-files-end-with-a-newline.

Comment: You're totally right and that's the way everyone should do that, but I prefer adapting the code to the user, not the other way around. ;)

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk the problem isn't so much the rare occurrence of a file with no terminal newline, but the much more common issue of file names with spaces. Using `while IFS=` makes this work on file names with spaces (or tabs, newlines etc) and using `-r` makes it work for file names with backslashes. Your `find` solution can deal with arbitrary file names, but the `while` approach needs the changes dessert suggested to make it robust.

Comment: @terdon: @dessert: I added `-r`, thanks for your help. But I'm still not sure why should I add `IFS=''` explicitly. The current solution with the default value of `IFS` makes `printf` correctly print filenames with spaces and tabs. Is this just to make sure that `IFS` is set to the correct value before starting the loop?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk the only case I'm aware of where it makes a difference (at least in current versions of bash) is if the filename *starts* with whitespace

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to use `xargs`:

```
xargs -a target_files_list.txt -d '\n' sed -i -- 's/SOME_TEXT/TEXT_TO_REPLACE/g'
```

From `man xargs`:

```
   -a file, --arg-file=file
          Read items from file instead of standard input.  

   --delimiter=delim, -d delim
          Input  items  are  terminated  by  the specified character.  The
          specified delimiter may be a single character, a C-style charac‐
          ter  escape  such as \n, or an octal or hexadecimal escape code.
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use a `for` loop.

```
IFS=$'\n' # Very important! Splits files on newline instead of space.

for file in $(cat files.txt); do
    sed ...
done
```

Note that you will run into problems if you encounter any files with newlines (!) in their names. (: